# How to loop through an iterator of indeterminate length with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm downloading a list of keys from an S3 bucket and I don't know how many there are. I stopped my process after 300,000 keys and 5 minutes, and I'd like to use asyncio (which I am only a rank beginner at. I used it to download a predetermined list of urls once) to speed up the process.

My current, synchronous, function goes like this:

```
def get_keys(s3, bucket_name, prefix):
    # s3 previously defined by boto3.resource('s3') with AWS key and secret key as kwargs
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    keys = []
    for item in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
        keys.append(item.key)
    return keys
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asyncio won't help you here, unfortunately.

Firstly and most importantly, `boto3` isn't asyncio aware; it doesn't know how to use the asyncio loop to do connections, it just works in a single synchronous thread. (Of course you can use several threads or `multiprocessing` subprocesses to make requests, but see below why that won't help either.)

The underlying S3 function call `.objects.filter` does is [`list_objects_v2`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2), which lets one list up to 1000 keys per request. If there are more than 1000 keys returned, the result value will contain `IsTruncated=True` and a `NextContinuationToken`, which you can use to get the following page of results.
You can't predict the sequence of `ContinuationToken`s, so you can't parallelize things by continuation token.

If you *do* know more about the prefixes you're looking for, you could parallelize by those, though – for example, if you're looking for prefix `'aaa/bbb'` and you know the keys thereunder might be `aaa/bbb/0...`, `aaa/bbb/1...`, `aaa/bbb/2...`, you can do those queries in parallel to eke out some more performance.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking that you needed aiohttp instead of requests when downloading urls, and that that paradigm would carry over to boto3. I guess I'll download the keys overnight or something, perhaps saving them as json files in batches and with a hard limit just in case this bucket is the biggest bucket ever.

Comment: Yeah, that's reasonable. Luckily the S3 API is pretty fast, though – I just tried with a bucket of 2215 objects, and it took 2.6 seconds to `aws s3 ls` it. I'd suggest appending the records into a file as one JSON object per line, also known as http://jsonlines.org/ . It's easy to grep and pretty error-tolerant too.